# React Native Storybook + Typescript - React is not defined

Tags: typescript, react-native, storybook

I tried setting up React Native with Storybook and when importing a `.tsx` component I was receiving an error:
`React is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What fixed it for me was, in my .tsx component, change:
`import React from "react";`

to:

`import * as React from "react";`

Comment: can you please provide any link regarding storybook + react native + typescript setup?